# Triggering an event by time

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I want to trigger an element to complete a css transition; however, I don't want to use any physical trigger such as hover, or click.  I want to start the transition at a specific time and then repeat at certain time intervals.  Can this completed using jquery.

Comment: Use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval)

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval and add transition class after certain time-frame and remove it after certain time-frame.

see this : - http://jsbin.com/jemotexono/1/edit?html,css,js,output

easiest way to write set Interval is : -

```
  setInterval(function(){
    //Your code goes here 

  },2000); //specify the time in milliseconds
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Try out the sample code 

**HTML**
<div></div>

**CSS**
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 1s;
}

**Java Script**
$(document).ready(function(){
    var width = 100;
    //set the specific time to trigger
    setTimeout(function(){ trigger(); }, 1000);
    //function which perform the tranisition repeatedly
                  function trigger(){      
    setInterval(function(){
        width = width +5;
        $("div").css("width",width); 
                          }, 1000);

}                            
});
```